Target native_assets failed Error in Flutter Application
ote: C:\Users\AVuser\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\android_intent_plus-4.0.3\android\src\main\java\dev\fluttercommunity\plus\androidintent\IntentSender.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\AVuser\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\android_intent_plus-4.0.3\android\src\main\java\dev\fluttercommunity\plus\androidintent\MethodCallHandlerImpl.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\AVuser\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\firebase_messaging-14.7.10\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\messaging\FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Target native_assets failed: Target native_assets required define AndroidArchs but it was not provided

I am getting this error even though I tried all possible ways
I tried changing sdk, config

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
